# Jenkins Build With Parameters shows old and new parameter fields

Tags: jenkins, parameters, jenkins-pipeline

My Jenkins shared pipeline, used by dozens of repos internally, has several parameter fields defined. We have several repos that initially used another library, or their own ad-hoc pipelines, but then imported the shared library.

In some of these cases, the "Build With Parameters" UI shows *both* the old and new parameters. We have re-run the pipelines several times, but the old fields won't go away.

If we create a *new* branch, only the new fields are shown.

I am thinking there's an xml file on the controller that we have to wipe, but I'm not sure where.

Has anyone seen this? What's the resolution?

#### Update 1

I went into the `jobs` folder for a branch showing this, and backed-up the `config.xml` file:

```
> cd /mnt/data/jenkins/jobs/<org>/jobs/workflows/jobs/<repo>/branches/jenkins-test/

> mv config.xml config.xml-bak
```

Upon re-running the job, it re-creates the `config.xml` and it has the same issue: old and new fields still showing.

So I deleted the entire `jenkins-test` branch folder. The job doesn't go away in the UI. I made a test commit to the branch in Github, Jenkins picked it up and ran it. It automatically re-created the `jenkins-test` folder on the controller, and upon re-trying Build With Parameters, it *still* shows the old and new params.

Got to keep digging...

#### Update 2

I created https://issues.jenkins.io/browse/JENKINS-69652 for this.

#### update 3

I confirmed the commit that triggered the build is the right commit in the source repo, and it is pulling the correct commit of the pipeline library.

#### Update 4

Interesting. I Replayed a run, and entered a dummy pipeline:

```
pipeline {
    agent none
    stages {
        stage ('hello') {
           steps {
               echo 'hello!'
           } 
        }
    }
}
```

Going back to the Build With Parameters UI, it now shows *only* the **old** parameter fields. ***Where is this coming from? Where is it stuck??***

Answer (score 1):

I know it's been a while, but in case anyone else came across this error:

In my case, it helped to put this on top of the shared library:

```
properties([]) // fixes that old properties still show up
```

In my case the old pipelines were scripted and the shared library is a declarative one, so I guess maybe the scripted parameters are stored somewhere else and can only be overriden by the scripted pipelines properties([]) function and not by the parameters {} block.

Comment: Interesting! Thanks for this. I've since left the place I had this problem at, so I can't test it. But it sounds like a legit theory.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

My first guess is that you're loading a Pipeline library implicitly and defining the parameters in that implicitly loaded Pipeline library.

Pipeline libraries that are loaded implicitly are loaded into the Jenkinsfile without requiring an `@Library` reference to load them.

Check the jobs and the parent folders of those jobs and the root for Pipeline libraries that are defined and have the 'Load implicitly" checkbox enabled.

Comment: Thanks, I checked that already though. That was my first thought, actually. I double-checked for that, and inspected the console for that initial checkout of another library. It's not that.